# Do I need to pay for Xbox Live Gold in order to play multiplayer Minecraft Windows 10 Edition with my friend on another Windows 10 PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We keep getting "Unable to connect to world." when we try to connect to each other's world over the internet. It also says on the store page

" - Play in the beta with up to 4 of your Xbox LIVE friends both near and far in online multiplayer."

Comment: Is your friend also using Minecraft Windows 10 edition? If he is using the regular PC version, but has Windows 10 as his operating system that is not the same and you will not be able to play together.

Comment: No we're both in the Minecraft Windows 10 Edition and both on the same latest version.

Answer (score 1):

> This whole thing is in alpha right now, and it’s only available to Android users. The alpha is free. You can sign up for the alpha here, but you will need an Xbox gamertag. It does not need to be tied to a Gold account, though.

You do not need a Gold account to do what you are describing.

Source: [Article from TechnoBuffalo](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2016/04/13/minecraft-realms-alpha-android-server/)

Comment: Thanks but why can't we connect to each other's world? We're both on the latest version of the Minecraft Windows 10 edition (0.15).

Comment: @user400424 I haven't played the game in **quite** some time but from what I've read, it seems like you have to use a "realm" or a server to do so.

Comment: While in-game there's an option to invite a friend via Xbox LIVE. If they didn't want people to use it as a direct 1:1 invitation for their fiends to play on their world, wouldn't  they have removed the option? I was thinking maybe we needed to open a port or something.

Comment: @user400424 Yes you would definitely need to make sure that port `19132` is accessible.